# What can i do to make this program return values that it's supposed to?

Tags: c, cs50

Program is supposed to take every pixel around the pixel and average color values.
It seems to be working fine visually, but obviously it is not as it doesn't pass the test. The only test it passes is 'pixel in the corner'.

I would really appreciate some hints on where the bug might be.
Here is the code:

```
  //iterate through each row and column
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            /*create variables to define 3x3 box for each pixel
            also create variables to store sum of each colour values for all elements of each box*/
            int highi = i + 1;
            int highj = j + 1;
            int counter = 0;
            int blue = 0;
            int red = 0;
            int green = 0;
            //iterate through each element of newly created box and add sums of colour values
            for(int lowi = i-1 ; lowi <= highi; lowi++)
            {
                if(lowi < 0)
                {
                    lowi = i;
                    
                }
                
                for (int lowj = j-1 ; lowj <= highj; lowj++)
                {
                    if(lowj < 0)
                    {
                        lowj = j;
                        
                    }
                      
                    blue += image[lowi][lowj].rgbtBlue;
                    red += image[lowi][lowj].rgbtRed;
                    green += image[lowi][lowj].rgbtGreen;
                    counter++;
                }
            //calculate average of colour values for each pixel    
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = blue/counter;
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = red/counter;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = green/counter;
            }
```

Comment: Because you write the new value back to the image while you are scanning it, your future pixel values will be corrupted.  Consider writing your new averaged values to a new location in memory instead of over the existing image.

Comment: You are counting pixels twice when i or j is 0.

Comment: @stark That was one of my thoughts, but then i'm confused as why does it pass 'pixel in the corner' check, where i or j will certainly be 0, and doesn't pass 'pixel in the middle' check. Upon investigating results it seems like my values were sums divided by 8 and not 9.

Comment: @Michael Dorgan it is writing to new location i think. The part i copied is only function to separate program that writes values in new location i believe.  Unless you suggest to create new variables for each average and within same function write them into each pixel?

Comment: Should you be always rounding down?  ie. If you have 8 pixels at 1, and 1 pixel at 0, should the average be 0 or 1?

Comment: I see a read from image[][] in your averaging and a write to image[][] at the end after words.  Since these are reading and writing to the same areas, it will cause issues and would explain why only the top corner comes out correct.  After that first write, your next average will be affected by the previous average update.

Comment: Downvote is probably because your code is not a self-contained, runnable program which makes it much harder to debug.

Comment: Stark @Michael Dorgan Thanks guys, i have changed the code using your tips and it is working now. I dont even know how to make your answers appear in the main thread instead of comments, or up vote them as i'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Add a quick answer you can upvote and accept then if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that OP was writing to his `image[][]` array while reading from it, this causing it to be in error after the first read/write pass.